# linq returning object even when null

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a query that looks like this:

```
var TheQuery = (from t in MyDC.Table
                where....
                select new MyModel()
                {
                    Property1 = (int?)... ?? 0
                }
```

Sometimes, the `where` clause in the query returns no data to do the `select`. When this happens, `MyModel` is null. I was hoping that with the `?? 0` for every property the query would still return an object with `Property1` set to 0.

How do I rewrite this so that when no data exists to fill MyModel, MyModel doesn't come back null?

Comment: can't you check the count. something like TheQuery.ToList().Count

Comment: Dont do that, use .Any() so that it doesnt have to actually count the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if there is nothing to select, then no MyModel will be created. TheQuery will be an empty IEnumerable.

I'm not sure what is happening if you are getting a list of null objects. I'm not sure how that is possible.

You can check to see if there are results to your query like this:

```
var TheQuery =  from t in MyDC.Table
                where....
                select new MyModel()
                {
                    Property1 = (int?)... ?? 0
                }

var after = TheQuery.Any() ? 
            TheQuery : 
            Enumerable.Range(0, 1).Select(k => new MyModel() { Property1 = 0 });
```